# Configure a cron schedule for different intervals (hour and days)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron, google-cloud-scheduler

Hello I am configuring jobs in GCP following the google cloud guide: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules?&_ga=2.226390674.-907001748.1582817924#defining_the_job_schedule

I have to configure a job which will be executed once on weekdays at 6am and once on weekends at 5am. I am not pretty sure if it is possible to configure this for several intervals of time with something like an and statment:

```
0 5 * * 1-5  # monday to friday 5 am.
0 6 * * 6,0  # saturday and sunday 5 am.
```

In what way I can combine this intervals, besides that I need to add others ones but I am not pretty sure how can I do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just create two separate jobs?

Answer (score 3):

You can't combine them in one record. The times do not match on any way. Of course if you have more jobs this eventually can be possible (depend on intervals)